# Lookup list with entries from calendar only for the past two weeks

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

we have a calendar where we enter when and which trainings will take place. Now I would like to use a lookup column in another list and **get the title of those trainings** (which is no biggie) but we need the trainings **only for the last two weeks.** Can someone suggest me a way to do this? I've tried with workflows in SharePoint designer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent list of the lookup column, you can create a new calculated column, which uses a formula like `=IF(([AssignDate]-Today())<14, Title,"")`. Then this column will have value only if the column AssignDate has a value for the last two weeks. Then change the look up column to get value from the calculated column. It shall work now.

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm. :D thank you :)